# how can I check multiple columns of a data set, In R?

Tags: r, logical-operators

Note: I'm new to R. Please be kind or don't reply! ;)

Got a dataset in .txt file format, which I loaded to variable "allData".

In this data set if I look for a certain condition eg: # of Male candidate, it works..

```
allMale <- (allData[,10] == " Male")
length(allMale[allMale==TRUE])
```

if I look for another condition eg: # of candidate with " <=50K" value, it works as well..

```
#allBelow50 <- (allData[,15] == " <=50K")
#length(allBelow50[allBelow50==TRUE])
```

But, if I combined both conditions it doesn't work!

```
allMaleBelow50 <- (allData[,10] == " Male" && allData[,15] == " <=50K")
length(allMaleBelow50[allMaleBelow50==TRUE])
```

End goal: from a data set (contains multiple column) I need the number of candidate that satisfies 2 or more conditions.

Thank you

Comment: Don't use `&&` - it is not the same as `&`.

Comment: And to see why `&&` isn't the same as `&` check `?base::Logic`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`'s `filter` function. It takes multiple conditions. Just check `?dplyr::filter`. Example:

```
> require(dplyr)
> DF <- mtcars
> head(DF)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
> filter(DF, cyl == 4)
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
3  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
5  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
6  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
7  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
8  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
9  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
10 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
11 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
> filter(DF, cyl == 4, hp > 100)
   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
1 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
2 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.6  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: Or `subset(mtcars, cyl == 4 & hp > 100)` or `with(mtcars, mtcars[cyl == 4 & hp > 100,] )` etc etc etc. `dplyr` is not required for this sort of basic activity.

Comment: not required, but if someone is struggling with the `&` operator it solves that (minor) problem by allowing `&` conditions to be passed as comma-separated arguments

Answer (score 1):

data.table is very convenient for this:

```
mtcarsdt = data.table(mtcars)
mtcarsdt[cyl==6][vs==1]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
2: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
3: 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
4: 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
```

or:

```
mtcarsdt[cyl==6 & vs==1]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
2: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
3: 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
4: 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
```

One can add any number of conditions.